# Javascript infinite loop traversing Javascript object

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, traversal

This process, traversing a Javascript object is causing an infinite loop.  The same code seems to work if I call it on initialize instead of on the key up event...Thanks for any help!

```
<form>
    <input id="searchBox" name="searchText" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="search()">
</form>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>


var searchText = ""

function search(){
    searchText = document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
    traverse(jsonData,process);
}

//traverse JSON object
function traverse(json,func) {
    for (var i in json) {
        func.apply(this,[i,json[i]]);
        if (json[i] !== null && typeof(json[i])=="object") {
            console.log("STEP IN");
            traverse(json[i],func);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `process` do?

Comment: It's supposed to find nodes in the JSON tree that contain the search string.  Right now it just outputs them in the console, but I will put them in an array for autocomplete when I get this fixed.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem? I don't see anything that looks like it should cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Try using `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: ^Don't listen to this dude, null is type "object". Definitely use hasOwnProperty tho, otherwise you'll traverse the prototype and other garbage.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily cause an infinite loop if the object is recursive:

```
jsonData = {};
jsonData.x = jsonData;
```

You could use weakmaps to keep track of which nodes you have visited and avoid the recursion.

```
var map = new WeakMap();

function traverse(data, func) {
  if (data != null || "object" !== typeof data || map.get(data)) { return; }

  map.set(data, true);

  for (var i in data) {
    func.apply(this, [i, data[i]]);
    console.log("STEP IN");
    traverse(data[i], func);
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Will the traverse function ever run for use . `if (data != null ||....{return;}`?